# How do I force call a SQLException when Unit Testing in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, sqlexception

I am running Java tests on JUnit 4.xx. I'm trying to force run a SQLException from the try block. I've ran Mockito in many different ways but I don't get the result that I want.

**Here is my main file:**

```
public boolean close()   {

    if (connection == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Connection never initialized!");
    }

    try {
        connection.close();
        return true;
    }

    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "close", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Here is my test file:**

```
@Test
public void testFail2() throws SQLException {

    JDBCConnection spyConnect = mock(JDBCConnection.class);

    given(spyConnect.getConnection()).willAnswer(invocationOnMock -> new SQLException());

    assertFalse(spyConnect.close());
}
```

In summary, how do I get the catch block to get executed so that I get 100% line coverage for my overall program?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your mock to throw an exception, you should use [`willThrow`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/BDDMockito.html#willThrow-java.lang.Class-), not `willAnswer`:

```
given(spyConnect.getConnection()).willThrow(new SQLException());
```

Comment: This doesn’t work because SQLException is a checked exception. I had to use a lambda expression for it work and willAnswer allows lambda expressions.

Comment: @SandeepNamburi `willThrow` can handle checked exceptions, but after rereading your question, something doesn't add up to me. If you want to test `JDBCConnection`, why are you mocking it?

Comment: I'm adding my code and unit tests into a pipeline that doesn't have access to a database. Therefore, everything needs to be mocked.

Comment: @SandeepNamburi you have the wrong idea here - you can't test a class that you've mocked.